# Swift4: nil loading local UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage

read many thread on this, but no luck, so probably I am missing something here.

Receiving nil while I am loading an image on viewDidLoad()

```
    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "1.png")
```

Image is in Media.xcassets created for this

[image]
Tried change 1.png in 1, tried clean, tried to close and reopen xcode. Nothing.

What I am missing here?

Comment: imageView.image = UIImage(named:”1”) just try it

Answer (score 4):

Your images are imported correctly, but your way of using them is incorrect

```
let sampleImage = UIImageView()
sampleImage.image = UIImage(named:"1")
```

And PS:  you don’t need the extension names when it’s imported to the `xcassets` folder

Comment: Please consider clicking on the green check mark if it was useful in any ways

Comment: Clicking on the green check mark below the voting does not require points, but I also assume that you have enough points now!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image using below code,

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1.png") // Extension is not required, still if you add extension then also it will work fine
```

OR

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading from the project *Assets.xcassets* folder, you should get the images by the name that you added to the image set, *not* the original name of the file(s), and that's actually so logical! Xcode should handles picking the appropriate image from the set based on what is the device (@2x, @3x...).

In your case, the name of the set is "1" thus you would get it as:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
```